# One to many relation in database with common related table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, one-to-many

Imagine that I have a Table **Cine**. It holds name, director, etc. of movies. It can start and finish in any time, and this time is created **dynamically**, in another Table: **Schedule**.
Thus, between **Cine-Schedule** there is **One-To-Many** relation. So, this would be solved by adding **Foreign Key** to **Schedule**. Some thing like this:

### Cine

#### ID Name

1...Matrix

---

### Schedule

#### CineID. From To...... WeekDay

1.. ........17.00. 19.00..... Wednesday

1...........20.00. 22.00.....Thursday

---

Now imagine that another table also wants to use this Scheduling, which is conceptually totally separated from **Cine**, let say **CarRevision**.

In this case, how would be "**better design**" of database.

- Adding another foreign ID to Schedule?

### Schedule

#### CineID. RevisionID From To...... WeekDay

1.. .........Null.............17.00. 19.00..... Wednesday

1............Null.............20.00. 22.00..... Thursday

Null.........325............14.13. 14.34..... Monday

---

- Creating another table, like **RevisionSchedule**, same with Schedule, but with -logically- different foreign ID?

---

- Other solution? What about if we have many -conceptually- different Tables that want to use Schedule?

Answer (score 0):

for proper normalization, you would remove cine_id from the schedule - since it is not directly part of the definition of a schedule

you would make a new table

```
cine_schedule
--------------
cine_id
schedule_id
start_date
end_date
```

you would also build other relationships as appropriate

```
car_schedule
--------------
car_id
schedule_id
```

etc.

Comment: So, your design would be to create distinct table for every one to many relation.